# Using Applescript to generate and write to an excel file

Tags: excel, macos, applescript

New to AppleScript but I'm working on a script that takes a folder of images, gets the name, color profile, width, height, and calculates the aspect ratio (WxH) of each image and exports all that information to an excel file.  I was able to do this successfully when simply writing to a .csv but now I actually want to write to a .xls so I can also do some conditional formatting to the aspect ratio column. Below is the block of code causing trouble. When I go to compile I get the following error:

> **AppleScript Compile Error**:
>
> Can’t set «class DPVu» of «class ccel» "A" & num to imgName. Access not allowed.

This error occurs on the first "set value of cell" statement.  If I comment each of these lines one at a time and compile, it throws the same error for each of them.

I've tried googling everything I can think to google and have found nothing helpful...

Code:

```
--counter variable for excel row placement. (row 1 is a header row)
set num to 2
            
repeat with img in imgFolder
    --write specs to excel file
    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        set value of Cell "A"&num to imgName
        set value of Cell "B"&num to imgColorProfile
        set value of Cell "C"&num to imgWidth
        set value of Cell "D"&num to imgHeight
        set value of Cell "E"&num to imgRatio
    end tell

--incremental counter for next excel row
    set num to num + 1
end repeat
```

Comment: Can you show the rest of the code? My hunch is how this bit is placed within it is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write simpler

```
set num to 2

repeat with img in imgFolder
    --write specs to excel file
    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        tell row num
            set value of cell 1 to imgName
            set value of cell 2 to imgColorProfile
            set value of cell 3 to imgWidth
            set value of cell 4 to imgHeight
            set value of cell 5 to imgRatio
        end tell
    end tell

--incremental counter for next excel row
    set num to num + 1
end repeat
```